# Difference between 1D and 3D Heisenberg model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-models

[As is given in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)) the $1$D Heisenberg model is:

$$ \hat{H} = -J\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} - h\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i  $$

And the $3$D Heisenberg model is:

$$ \hat{H} = -\tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N \left( J_x \sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x + J_y \sigma_i^y \sigma_{i+1}^y + J_z \sigma_i^z \sigma_{i+1}^z +h\sigma_i^z \right) $$

As far as I have understood in case of both $1$D and $3$D models the spins $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1}$ has all the three components $(x,y,z)$. But the coupling constant $J$ has three components $J_x$, $J_y$, $J_z$ in case of $3$D Hamiltonian but in case of $1$D Hamiltonian it is only $J$. So this implies that the interactions between nearest neighbours is only along one direction in case of $1$D and all the three directions $(x,y,z)$ in case of $3$D. Is this the difference or is there any other explanation?